# Redis Sentinel notification not triggered when slave is down

Tags: database, redis, redis-sentinel

I have a redis cluster of 1 master and 2 replica registered in sentinel .I received a +sdown message when the sentinel was down. No action was taken and the situation remained same. But did not receive any further +sdown messages for the cluster as the cluster is in the same state for quite some time. is it expected behaviour?

Could not find anything in the documentation.
need to understand why +sdown is triggered only once even the situation remained same for quite some time.